# Function pointer as template argument, type deduction failing

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I was trying to use a function pointer as non-type template argument, but sometimes I do not understand why it fails to deduce the type.

Here an example

```
template <class T, class U, class R>
R sum(T a, U b) { return a + b; }

template <class T, class R, R (*Func)(T, R)>
R reduce(T *in, R initial, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        initial = Func(in[i], initial);
    return initial;
}

int main() {
    double data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << "Sum: " << reduce<sum>(data, 0.0, 5) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Unluckily it seems GCC does not provide a reason for the fail:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:15:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘reduce(double [5], double, int)’
test.cpp:15:64: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:7:3: note: template<class T, class R, R (* Func)(T, R)> R reduce(T*, R, int)
test.cpp:7:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Instead, specifying all the data types will make it work:

```
std::cout << "Sum: " << reduce<double, double, sum>(data, 0.0, 5) << "\n";
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake that you provide partial specialization of template. There works rule all or nothing. So if you change signature as follow:

```
template <class T, class R>
 R reduce(R (*Func)(T, R), T *in, R initial, int len) {
```

...

```
reduce(sum, data, 0.0, 5)
```

Everything compiled fine

Comment: Awww gosh I always forgot about not allowed partial specialization in template functions! Anyway, I am not allowed to pass functions as parameters of a functions (but I am to pass them in templates). So I guess I have to fully specialize the call.